# Установка плагина ObjectivEclipse

Tags: objective-c, ide, eclipse, плагин

Привет.

Если знаете, то напишите подробную инструкцию по установке плагина ObjectivEclipse для Eclipse. Не могу с этим разобраться.

Спасибо.

Comment: [Так вот же FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/objectiveclipse/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_install_ObjectivEClipse?)

Comment: @Dex,   
> Assuming you're running Mac OS X

Answer (score 1):

Цитата из FAQ:

> **Does it work on non-Apple platforms?**
> Not at the current time.

Так что, насколько могу судить, работа этого плагина возможна только в Mac OS X, а у вас Windows (ведь верно?).